# installed Xampp on Windows 7 32-bit. Errors when starting

Tags: mysql, xampp

When I try to start MySql in XAMPP control panel (v3.2.1) I have the following message and MySql does not start.

```
23:02:03  [mysql]   Problem detected!
23:02:03  [mysql]   Port 3306 in use by ""C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqld" --defaults-file="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\my.ini" MySQL"!
23:02:03  [mysql]   MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
23:02:03  [mysql]   You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
23:02:03  [mysql]   or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
23:02:03  [mysql]   Attempting to start MySQL service...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The port `3306` is already in use in your machine, so you need to change the port number to `3307` in `my.ini` in  `C:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini`.

Once done restart the Apache server.

Answer (score 0):

To change the port successfully, you have to change the port number in following files in the mentioned manner.

1. You can change the port number to 3306 from 3307 in
   \xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini file in a couple of places.
2. There is also a couple of default MySQL port settings in the
   \xampp\php\php.ini file that would also need changing.
3. Save the files and restart Apache and MySQL to test.

Also make sure you run it as administrator (always helps)

Comment: This error is coming again and again after changing the port number

Comment: Problem detected!
13:26:37  [mysql]  Port 3306 in use by ""C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\mysqld-nt" --defaults-file="C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\my.ini" MySQL"!
13:26:37  [mysql]  MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
13:26:37  [mysql]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
13:26:37  [mysql]  or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port

Comment: The first line should of gave you what the error message was, its still saying Port 3306 is still being used. You need to change this as something else may be using this port or has it as reserve etc. Google "How to change xampp mySQL port"