# Unable to start MySql server with windows 7 (32-bit) and XAMPP-win32-5.6.32

Tags: mysql, windows, xampp, 32bit-64bit

I had installed XAMPP-win32-5.6.32. Everything works fine, Apache start successfully but when I am attempting to start MySql server it show error given as below.

```
Attempting to start MySQL service...
10:14:03 PM  [mysql]    Executing "net start "mysql""
10:14:04 PM  [mysql]    Return code: 0
```

I had changed port from 3306 to 3307 in both my.ini and php.ini files as mentioned in given link.
[[installed Xampp on Windows 7 32-bit. Errors when starting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32917766/installed-xampp-on-windows-7-32-bit-errors-when-starting][1])

I also find similar questions which is already asked but there is no satisfactory answers. Here is the question which has similar problem as given in this link.
[[Cannot execute MySQL service, XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36979998/cannot-execute-mysql-service-xampp][1])

I followed these steps also but still unable to run mysql server on one of my system.

Comment: Run `net start mysql` manually from a command line and see if it reports an error.

Comment: thanks for your concern @AlexK. . I run that command it is geving "System error 2 has occured."
 The System cannot find the files specified.

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23624234/how-to-change-the-path-of-mysql-services

Comment: "Alternatively you can search for c:\Program Files\MySQL\mysqld in registry and change to C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin". According to that statement I need to change the path of "mysqld" but I did not find that file in my C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\

Comment: I tried searching mysql in regedit.exe but did not even find ImagePath in the list.

Comment: @Jiten: can you try using the XAMPP control panel to start the MySQL?  You can find the control panel in the xampp directory.

Comment: @PaulT. my problem was the same. I was trying to start mysql from XAMPP control panel but it's showing same error in control panel as I mention in my question above.

Comment: @AlexK. Kindly suggest other ways to resolve that issue.